# Formula To Calculate Accrued Quarterly Allowance Based On Employment Length

Tags: google-sheets, formula

Employees get a specified amount of allowance for each quarter of the year, which accrues as the year progresses, and resets each new year. The amount they get each quarter is determined by how long they have been employed.

```
YEARS EMPLOYED | $ PER QUARTER
<1 | $0
>=1 | $37.5
>=3 | $66.66
>=5 | $100
```

Using only one reference cell (the hire date in Cell O1), I'm trying to figure out how to put a formula together which would display the sum of all quarterly amounts accrued this year to date.

The part that is giving me trouble is that when the amount per quarter changes during the year (due to the number of years employed reaching the next level), any previous quarters for the year need to remain at their previously assigned amounts, for example:

If the HIRE DATE is April 16, 2015:

```
QUARTER | YEARS HIRED | QUARTERLY ALLOWANCE
Q1 | 2.71 | $37.5
Q2 | 2.96 | $37.5
Q3 | 3.21 | $66.66
Q4 | 3.46 | $66.66
```

If TODAY'S DATE is May 21, 2018, the total allowance amount to date = $75 (Q1+Q2)

If TODAY'S DATE is Oct 7, 2018, the total allowance amount to date = $208.32 (Q1+Q2+Q3+Q4)

How can this be done with one formula, using only the hire date in Cell O1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest way to get the number of complete years hired is to use Datedif:

```
=DATEDIF(O$1,DATE(YEAR(P$1),RIGHT(A2)*3-2,1),"Y")
```

placed in (say) E2, where the current date is in P1 and the list of quarters starts in A2

Then a lookup to get the allowance calculated on the first day of each quarter:

```
=LOOKUP(E2,{0,1,3,5},{0,37.5,66.66,100})
```

and finally a check to see if the first day of the quarter is on or before the current date:

```
=P1>=DATE(YEAR(P1),MONTH(RIGHT(A2)*3-2),1)
```

Then you could get the total from

```
=SUMPRODUCT(F2:F5*G2:G5)
```

Or you could combine all this into one big array-type formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((P1>=DATE(YEAR(P1),{1,4,7,10},1))*LOOKUP(DATEDIF(O1,DATE(YEAR(P1),{1,4,7,10},1),"Y"),{0,1,3,5},{0,37.5,66.66,100}))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help with this with this, it works perfectly!